# Unable to pass data to directive through ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using Angular's `components`, though I have injected `ngCart` into my app which use `directives`. I need to pass data from a form (billing details) with ngCart's `checkout()` function so I can include both the billing details and transactions details in a single JSON to send to the back-end.

I am passing the billing object as an argument for the `checkout()` function but it is logging as undefined. If I change the object to a string, it does log to the `ngcartCheckout` directive, so there is an issue with gathering the data from the object.

***Question***

Why is the object failing to be passed to the `ngcartCheckout` directive?

```
<div>
   <input ng-model="foo.name">
   <input ng-model="foo.sname">
</div>

<div ng-if="service=='http' || service == 'log'">
    <button ng-click="checkout(foo)">Checkout</button>
</div>
```

---

```
.directive('ngcartCheckout', [function(){
        return {
            restrict : 'E',
            controller : ('CartController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'ngCart', 'fulfilmentProvider', function($rootScope, $scope, ngCart, fulfilmentProvider) {
                $scope.ngCart = ngCart;

                $scope.checkout = function (foo) {
                    console.log(foo)
                }
            }]),
            scope: {
                service:'@', //REMOVED FROM TEMPLATE AS NOT RELEVANT
                settings:'=' //REMOVED FROM TEMPLATE AS NOT RELEVANT
            },
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
               if ( typeof attrs.templateUrl == 'undefined' ) {
                  return 'p3sweb/app/components/checkout/views/ngCart/checkout.htm';
               } else {
                   return attrs.templateUrl;
               }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Why are you using ng-model on <p> tag?

Comment: I am using form elements, I just used it for an example

Comment: An incorrect example I know

Answer (score 0):

foo is never declared (at least not in your example) add

```
$scope.foo = {};
```

above

```
$scope.ngCart = ngCart;
```

Now it will spit out an empty object, if you want it to assign the name and sname to foo you would need to change the p tag to an input and type the name into the input

```
<input ng-model="foo.name">
```